# Gauss's Law for Electric Dipole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, gauss-law, dipole-moment

[image]

Hello, in this question i tried applying Gauss's law for electric fields since on its Left-hand Side I will have the electric flux. My question is why is the enclosed charge not equal to zero at first ? Moreover, I tried to use the electric dipole moment as
$$\mathbf{p} = Q \mathbf{l},$$
where $\mathbf{l} = d \mathbf{\hat{z}}$ and $\mathbf{p} = p_0 \mathbf{\hat{z}}$.

Therefore, $q = \frac{p_0}{d}.$

Finally, the flux will be $\frac{p_0}{d \epsilon_0}$.

After further research, my answer is wrong and should contain a negative sign (D is the right answer), but I don't know where I went wrong in my implications.

I would really appreciate it if you could help me, and thank you for your assistance.

Comment: "Two charges at distance $d$..." Distance $d$ from where?

Comment: Do you know how is the direction of the dipole moment vector defined? Which of the two charges is inside the cylinder?

Comment: This is a homework-like / check my work question.  Please don't respond.

Comment: @PhilipWood it might seem that one charge will be on the bottom circular surface of the cylinder and the other on the top one, since the dipole moment is pointing from the negative to the positive charge, and these 2 charges should be at distance d from each other

Comment: @PAM I agree that the negative charge is below the positive charge, but the question doesn't say that the charges are distance $d$ apart, nor does it say where they are. Neither does it give a sign convention for flux through the cylinder.  My advice for doing this sort of question would *usually* be to start by drawing a quick sketch of the electric field lines, but in this case I think you have a bad question and that you shouldn't spend any more time on it.

Comment: Just for knowledge this is neither a homework nor a graded exercise I should submit, I'm training for my next electromagnetism exam and stumbled upon this question